# Tomar una subcadena de una cadena de texto

Tags: python

Me gustaría tomar de una cadena de texto una subcadena, pero a partir de un punto en concreto.
Me explico.
Tengo una lista así:
(Es una lista de ejemplo)

```
Lista=['Estoesunacadena/01/01/hola', 'Estoesunacadena/01/02/QueTal','Estoesunacadena/01/03/Adios']
```

Entonces me gustaría que de cada una de ellas obtuviese una subcadena que comience tras la segunda barra, es decir, obtener:

```
01/hola
02/QueTal
03/Adios
```

¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código te puede ser útil

```
list_of_str =['Estoesunacadena/01/01/hola', 'Estoesunacadena/01/02/QueTal', 'Estoesunacadena/01/03/Adios']

for element in list_of_str:
    new_list = element.split('/')
    print(f"{new_list[2]}/{new_list[3]}")
```

la función split('/') separa la cadena en donde encuentra un /, puedes reemplazar ese carácter por cualquier otro, luego imprimes los 2 últimos elementos de tu nueva lista.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias!